# Can't connect Angular app to Java backend

Tags: angular, proxy

I have a backend at:
example.com/ab

I would like to connect my local Angular environment to it

My proxy configuration:

```
{
  "/ab": {
    "target": "http://example.com/ab",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

But I get:

[image]

How to configure the proxy properly?

Comment: There should not be the `/ab` part in the `target` attribute or you will end up proxying to `http://example.com/ab/ab`. Please try with `"target": "http://example.com",`

Answer (score 1):

(This should be a comment but I don't have enough place)

Can you try :

```json
  {
    "context": [
      '/ab',
    ],
    "target": "http://example.com",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
```